# CPU requirements for Minecraft Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hardware, performance

Most questions ask about how much RAM or how much bandwidth a Minecraft server needs, but I haven't found much information on CPU requirements.

Let's say I have the following specs for a dedicated server:

- 64GB RAM
- [Intel i9 9900K](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i9-processors/i9-9900k.html) - 8 cores / 16 threads; 3.5 - 5.0 ghz
- 1Gbps bandwidth
- Enough nvme storage

How many 2GB RAM vanilla servers with ~8 players each can I run?

Assume no redstone contraptions and a view distance of <= 10 chunks.

The RAM and bandwidth should allow me to run 31 servers (leaving 2GB of RAM to the OS), but I'm not sure if the CPU would be powerful enough.

I see a lot of varying information: some say you need a fairly powerful CPU, and others say that the CPU doesn't really matter; if you have enough RAM and bandwidth you should be alright.

Comment: It’s a reasonable question but I wouldn’t expect any answers which are both specific and reliable. You’re just going to have to run some tests.

Comment: In 1.14 the server CPU usage is very high anyway. If you worry mainly about performance, play 1.12.2.

Comment: The reason why most questions deal with RAM is probably because that's the main bottleneck. You don't need to get a better CPU if it doesn't get used due to low RAM. Also, I recommend you to not set the render distance lower than 10, that affects mob spawning and despawning, up to a point where you might get no mob spawns at all anymore in certain areas or they accumulate in other places.

Comment: @FabianRöling Would need 1.13 for forceload command. Yeah I probably wouldn't set it lower than 10.

Comment: Chunk loading is only broken in 1.14, in 1.12 you can build proper chunk loaders.

Comment: @FabianRöling Would want to use it to pregenerate world and keep the entire world loaded during a UHC match. So I don't think building chunk loaders would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a currently untested and possibly incorrect answer:

With the specs mentioned in the question, one should be able to host at least 31 UHC survival servers with 8 slots, and likely more for other minigame servers.

---

I read on https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/how-many-players-could-a-server-with-64gb-ram-4-5ghz-manage.363798/

> Remii: Intel® Core™ i9-9900K Octa-Core (The BEST CPU for big static server currently) 1.13.2 ~55 Minigame Server with 18 filled Slots

This figure is 4 times higher than 31 servers with 8 slots.

UHC is probably more taxing on the CPU, and Minecraft 1.14 is likely slower.

Comment: This is just a warning for people, Minecraft Servers run less efficient when given 13+ GB of RAM so I recommend going with 12 GB, and a very good CPU (for example 10900X) because it's an amazing 1 core performance and generally a good processor.